# Callkit - No audio if starting a call from background

Tags: ios, background, webrtc, voip, callkit

This started to happen since iOS 13.3.1

On my app I use Callkit + WebRTC to establish VOIP connections. I always managed to establish connections without an issue.

However, since 13.3.1 that I'm not able to start a Callkit call if the app's not on the foreground: I manage to establish the connection but the callkit isn't started (no green icon/bar on the top) and the microphone isn't picked up also.

I always get the following error:

```
Error requesting transaction ((  
    " contactIdentifier=(null) video=0 relay=0 upgrade=0 retry=0 emergency=0 isVoicemail=0 ttyType=0 localLandscapeAspectRatio={0, 0} localPortraitAspectRatio={0, 0} dateStarted=(null) localSenderIdentityUUID=(null) shouldSuppressInCallUI=0>"  
)): (Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=6 "(null)")
```

From what I've gathered (there is almost no information about this code 6 error) Callkit may terminate if the AudioSession isn't active. However I'm not understanding what happened since 13.3.1 to affect this on background (I have Audio,Airplay and PIP / Voice over IP / Background fetch) modes active.

In the meanwhile I tried numerous things, from activating the session myself (both before callController.request and also before provider.reportOutgoingCall)

```
 do {  
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat, options: .mixWithOthers)  
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)  
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)  
} catch {  
    print(error)  
}
```

to playing a silent audio (trying to force the AVAudioSession to activate) but had no luck whatsoever.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same thing when I implement call kit with my project, I tried everything with AudioSession but turns out it was related to library which I was using for webrtc and sip, there was one line inside webrtc library which check application state if it is in background or not, if it is if was not connecting audio. So my advice is check webrtc code base or search inside the codes for app state checks like  `UIApplicationStateBackground` or directly `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState`.

I hope this will help!

Comment: What library do you use?

Comment: @famfamfam library we are using is Mediastreamer2. Inside there is file named **iphonesnd.m**. Audio session is starting in this class. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category(rawValue: convertFromAVAudioSessionCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)), options: [.allowBluetooth])
    try session.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat)
    try session.setPreferredSampleRate(44100.0)
    try session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.005)
} catch {
    print("Error configuring audio session webrtc",error)
}
```

Note: Use the Category to "playback". Do not use "playAndRecord" for AVAudioSession which causes the No Audio in background mode.